# How to disable schema locking on all services on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, schema-locks

I have a situation in which all services published to an ArcGIS Server (10.6.1) were published with schema locking enabled. I would like a way to disable schema locking on all services without having to go into each one and set the schemalockingEnabled parameter to false.

The source datasets are mostly from an enterprise geodatabase (SQL Server 2017).

I'm looking for a python solution, possibly using the ArcGIS API for Python. Unless there's a non-programmatic way to accomplish this.

Is this possible?

Comment: Similarly, is there a way to have new services created without schema locking by default?  As it is, I just have to remember to check recently created services from time to time and turn off schema locking for them.  This is tedious as they are in various different folders/groups.

Comment: Did you try the following? - https://community.esri.com/thread/236055-disable-schema-locking-on-multiple-published-services